# Does removeobjectforkey also remove the key

Tags: ios, objective-c

For an `NSMutableDictionary`, does `removeObjectForKey:` remove both the object and the key from the dictionary?

Comment: Please read the documentation before asking a question like this. The docs for `NSMutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:` clearly gives you the answer: *"Removes a given key and its associated value from the dictionary."*

Comment: If you want to remove the object only without removing key, try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it removes both the object and the key associated with that object.

[As Apple's documentation says:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/removeObjectForKey%3a)

> Removes a given key and its associated value from the dictionary.